# Check if a column is varchar or not

Tags: sql, regex, plsqldeveloper

i have written a query when i am getting column names in varchar and number.now i want to to find out if the column is varchar then i have to apply another condition and in case of of number another condition. FOR EG :-

```
Select employee_num,name from table;
```

where employee_num ,name can be anything  number/varchar. is there a regular exp to find out ?

I Tried this

```
select ..... where regexp_like(<column> , '^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$');
```

but this is not working

Comment: If you know it is a number, why do you need to find out? The type doesn't suddenly change.. Why do you think you need regular expressions for this? Your question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Okay. Then I would again have to ask you for additional clarification. Since my answer was obviously not what you were looking for.

Comment: Regular expression applied to what?

Comment: select ..... where regexp_like(<column> , '^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$');
Something like this

Comment: This will restrict which rows show up in your results. It will not do anything to "tell" you what type a given column is. You really need to look at the table definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
-- Not Numbers
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(col1, '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '');

-- Numbers
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col1, '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '')
```

[Link to SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60050/4)

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get a complete picture of your requirements. If you are building a dynamic query and wants to verify the data type of columns in SELECT clause then please make use of DBA_TAB_COLUMNS or ALL_TAB_COLUMNS or USER_TAB_COLUMNS based on your access level/security requirements. These are dynamic views that provides information regarding columns belonging to a table or view along with data type.

You may write a separate function like

```
function xx_get_data_type(
p_column_name in varchar2, 
p_table_name in varchar2
) return varchar2
is
    lv_return_data_type     varchar2(30);
begin
    select
        data_type
    into
        lv_return_data_type
    from
        dba_tab_columns
    where
        table_name like p_table_name and column_name like p_column_name;

    return(lv_return_data_type);
exception
    when no_data_found then
        <your error error handling code here...>
    when others then
        <your error handling code here...>    
end;
```